# Is there a way to specify an alternate xsd source for a single namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have some XML files using [the Schema Instance Namespace (xsi)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#xsi-namespace) as schema definition.  I wish I could validate them on [almost] public machines over an online schema (being a public [ISO20022 Standard](https://www.iso20022.org/)) and over a copy of that schema on a local server which resides on a DMZ.

How can I specify an alternate source of location for the same namespace ?

Is this a correct attempt ?

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02 file:///dir/on/local/server/in/DMZ/pacs.003.001.02.xsd
      urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.02 https://cdn.rawgit.com/deeppay/deeppay-sepa/master/xsd/pacs.003.001.02.xsd">
```

Comment: Normally you would set up a catalog or a resolver to map HTTP URIs to local file URIs.

Comment: It depends on the schema validator you are using. Most will have some kind of mechanism for this, for example the JAXP validation API allows you to specify a SchemaResolver. Please indicate how you are invoking the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You ask "is this a correct attempt", indicating that you are prepared to change the xsi:schemaLocation attribute to point to a different location. That's certainly a workable and straightforward way of doing it, though it might be inconvenient if you are validating many documents.

Most schema validators will have some kind of mechanism for redirecting to a local copy of the schema, for example the JAXP validation API allows you to specify a SchemaResolver, and you can use this mechanism with a catalog that defines the local locations.

Alternatively the API will often allow you to specify the schema that you want to validate against explicitly, ignoring the `xsi:schemaLocation` entirely. (After all, if you don't trust the document to be valid, why would you trust it to tell you where to find the right schema for validation?)

Please indicate how you are invoking the validation.